# Converting a CFG to CNF

Tags: context-free-grammar, automata, computation-theory, chomsky-normal-form

I am trying to convert a CFG to a CNF, but I am unsure what to identify as 'variables'. Here is the problem:

```
S -> aA | ABa 
A -> AA | a  
B -> AbA | bb
```

I have added a new start variable to make it

```
S' -> S  
S -> aA | ABa 
A -> AA | a  
B -> AbA | bb
```

Then, after unit production removal, it is:

```
S' -> aA | ABa 
S -> aA | ABa 
A -> AA | a  
B -> AbA | bb
```

I know the next step would be to change any production that have more than 2 variables, but is ABa three variables? Or is it two variables and a terminal?

If it is two variables and a terminal, to finally simplify it, am I able to create something like this:

```
S' -> aA | Xa  
S -> aA | Xa  
A -> AA | a  
B -> Yb | bb  
X -> AB
Y -> AA
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure that whoever set that problem uses the convention that capital letters are non-terminals ("syntactic variables") and lower-case letters are terminals. I'm also pretty sure that they mention that fact somewhere. (It's clear that there is no production which expands `a`, right? That is why you didn't remove `A->a` while you were removing unit productions.)

Answer (score 0):

The grammars in the Chomsky normal form has the following production formats:

```
A → BC, or
A → a,  or
S → ε,
```

It is made of symbols (`a`, `A`...). These symbols are in two sets: terminal symbols (as `a` and `b`, lower case letters, both part of the alphabet) and non terminal symbols (as `A` and `B`, upper case letters). The grammar also has productions (like `S → a`), and a starting symbol (a non-terminal) `S`.

You start from this grammar (there is no need of new starting rule):

```
S → aA | ABa
A → AA | a
B → AbA | bb
```

Separate the concatenations into their own productions:

```
S → aA 
S → ABa
A → AA
A → a
B → AbA
B → bb
```

Move all terminal symbols into their own non-terminal symbols (`a` into `C` (but keep the `a` in `A`, because its already valid in the CNF) and `b` into `D`):

```
S → CA 
S → ABC
A → AA
A → a
B → ADA
B → DD
C → a
D → b
```

Split the the right hand sides where there are more than two non-terminal symbols:

```
S → CA 
S → AE
A → AA
A → a
B → AF
B → DD
C → a
D → b
E → BC
F → DA
```

Then you are done.